# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, wubi, system-installation

I installed Wubi a little while ago to try out Ubuntu and I really like it so I decided to make a partition and install 13.10 fully. When I booted from my USB with 13.10 and tried installing it using the recommended settings it said that there was an error regarding either my CD disk (I don't have one) or my hard disk.

I was unaware of any issues to my hard drive. I think it started to install and make the partition because I now how a second partition with some files in it that looks like they would belong to 13.10 but it does not show up as a boot option. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd84789a3

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2463743     1230848    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         2464560   474346923   235941182    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       474347518   625141759    75397121    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       474347520   617172991    71412736   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       617175040   625141759     3983360   82  Linux swap / Solaris
dcolligan@ubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0       29G   20G  9.1G  68% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           751M  936K  750M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  240K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda2       226G  157G   69G  70% /host
/dev/sda5        67G  104M   64G   1% /media/eee7c5a6-3f76-4c20-a374-7217a090a674
/dev/sda1       1.2G  659M  544M  55% /media/SYSTEM_DRV
```

Comment: Check the drive for the bad blocks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. Sorry I'm new to linux.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `sudo fdisk -lu
df -h`

Comment: Done thank you I can fix the formatting if you need me to, also.

Comment: Wild Man posted 2 separate commands: `sudo fdisk -lu` and `df -h`.

Comment: @Danatela Fixed it sorry.

Comment: I just unmounted the partition that I made when I tried to install 13.10 and I am running `bad blocks -nsv /dev/sda5` its been a few hours and it's only 50% done however no bad blocks have been found yet.

Comment: This question seems to have been abandoned. There has not been further information or activity added to it for several months, and the questioner has not logged in since shortly after it was first posted.  I am flagging this to be closed. If you think this issue is still affecting you, you can flag a moderator to re-open it.